# Send my ajax text field to php input value

Tags: php, jquery

Hi am trying to print the value of `<span class="paymentID" name="txn_id">ABC</span></div>` ABC into my input field named `txn`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#test2").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
  });
  $("#btn3").click(function(){

    var result  = getElementByClass('.paymentID');
    $('#txn').val("result");
    $("#test3").val("Dolly Duck");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="paymentID" name="txn_id">ABC</span></div>
<input type="text" name="txn" id="txn" value="">


<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another paragraph.</p>

<p>Input field: <input type="text" id="test3" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>

<button id="btn1">Set Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Set HTML</button>
<button id="btn3">Set Value</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is blank? And where? And when? Your description is incomplete and unclear, so it's hard to tell specifically what the problem is. Describe it in detail, mentioning the flow of the code, the specific variable you are talking about and so on. Also it's unclear how demoSuccessHandler() is being called.

Comment: you must fill the input in complete function.
like this ```var payment_ID = document.getElementById('payment_ID');``` and after that you must fill it
```
payment_ID.value = r
```

Comment: `var result  = $(".paymentID").val();
    $('#txn').val(result);`

Comment: you seem to have almost entirely changed the code. Is it even relating to the same problem??

Comment: Anyway, what is getElementByClass supposed to be? Is it your function or something? Either way, you don't need it. You can use jQuery (to be consistent with the rest of your code) to do that, e.g. `var result = $(".paymentID");`. The secondly `$('#txn').val("result");` just puts the literal string "result" into the textbox, because of the quote marks. And `result` wouldn't work either because that's the object, not the text. `$('#txn').val(result.text());` should do the job.